# IWAB0506E Error in Copying Axis Jar Files to Web Project

Tags: java, web-services

The problem I'm facing is the following error: IWAB0506E Error when copying Axis jar files to web project.

I've tried copying the jar file in the /lib folder of the project folder, but the issue persists. Could someone please provide insights into what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it?